# Why doesn't after() function work with clone() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
        $(".block p").clone().after(".block");
        $(".block p").remove();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="block">
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

That's just a simple example summarizing what I'm trying to do. I want to get a clone of an element place it after a block, and then delete the element that I copied.

I've no clue why after() func doesn't work. How can I achieve what I want to do?

Comment: You want `insertAfter()`

Comment: If you're removing the element you're inserting after, isn't that the same as `replaceWith()`?

Answer (score 0):

[after()](https://api.jquery.com/after/) expects content as argument to be inserted into the matching element(s)

You can simply move the existing one in one step without needing to clone it and then remove the original

```js
const $block = $(".block");     
$block.after($block.find('p'));
```

```css
.block {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 1em
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```